# Sampling random points over each class of a Classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, stratified-sampling

I performed an Unsupervised Classification in GEE and I have 3 classes. I need to create random points in each class in order to draw a histogram of spectral signature later.

In line 150 of [the script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/dc813fab061b269784857b4caf757d1e) I tried to use stratifiedSample to create 100 points per class, but it takes a very long time and does not finish and gives the error:

> Layer 2: Layer error: The service is currently unavailable.

I do not think mapping 300 points is so difficult for GEE. How can I add these random points to my classification classes?